# Python: requests.get("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/") nunca retorna nada

Tags: python, python-requests

Ao tentar usar um `requests.get(url)` não obtenho nenhuma resposta do servidor, porém, adicionando o kwarg
 `timeout=1` por exemplo, obtenho a resposta depois de 1 segundo...
exemplo:\

```
import requests

url = "https://google.com/"
r = requests.get(url, timeout=1)
print(r.elapsed)
```

obtenho

`0:00:01.211611`.

se usar

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
```

obtenho:

`0:00:05.223328`.

Pelo que percebi a função só me retorna algo quando chega no timeout.
Talvez esteja fazendo algo muito errado, mas acho que eu deveria receber uma resposta do get assim que o servidor responder e não após o timeout...

Obti o Seguinte resultado imprimindo o r.**dict** (retirei o content)

```
_content_consumed True
_next None
status_code 200
headers {'Date': 'Mon, 29 Jun 2020 20:40:42 GMT', 'Expires': '-1', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1', 'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Server': 'gws', 'Content-Length': '5387', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Set-Cookie': '1P_JAR=2020-06-29-20; expires=Wed, 29-Jul-2020 20:40:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure, NID=204=AuH0fx2X4m3kT6AeVtg0YMDEGr6uehL7Kt8WyzO7cmIlNDq_qnh4QXcUybI9aPOMAuC8_PuHsidpBN--vMfU1jJRreb2lM340XOSv2-CZAkK1qfXbrSSii9cRG-uX1caNB3HlnL4QDjErvgcYPtedlatyvLEaLALJ4Lj0aigT7c; expires=Tue, 29-Dec-2020 20:40:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly'}
raw <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f1cb7b5f0b8>
url http://www.google.com/
encoding ISO-8859-1
history []
reason OK
cookies <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie 1P_JAR=2020-06-29-20 for .google.com/>, <Cookie NID=204=AuH0fx2X4m3kT6AeVtg0YMDEGr6uehL7Kt8WyzO7cmIlNDq_qnh4QXcUybI9aPOMAuC8_PuHsidpBN--vMfU1jJRreb2lM340XOSv2-CZAkK1qfXbrSSii9cRG-uX1caNB3HlnL4QDjErvgcYPtedlatyvLEaLALJ4Lj0aigT7c for .google.com/>]>
elapsed 0:00:05.147145
request <PreparedRequest [GET]>
connection <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x7f1cb6d8e1d0>
[Finished in 6.0s]
```

Percebi também que em páginas de html mais simples como:
http://www.brainjar.com/java/host/test.html 
o problema não acontece e eu recebo a resposta quase imediatamente.
0:00:00.212320.

Comment: Veja esse se [exemplo](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/RequestTimeout) o ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O facto de retornar apenas no fim do timeout leva-me a crer que o request esteja a falhar.
Corri o código praticamente como está e funcionou.
É possível que a tua firewall esteja a bloquear o executável python? Experimenta imprimir o status code.

```
url = "https://google.com/"
r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
print(r.elapsed)
print(r.status_code)

0:00:00.180191
200
```

Comment: Adicionei novas informações no problema

Comment: E sim, eu recebo a response 200

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de descobrir que o problema ocorre quando faço o request usando o ipv6.
Ao usar o ipv4, o problema não ocorre.

Esse código retirado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046733/force-requests-to-use-ipv4-ipv6 Resposta do usuario:Jeff Kaufman, resolveu meu problema.

```
# Monkey patch to force IPv4, since FB seems to hang on IPv6
import socket
old_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
def new_getaddrinfo(*args, **kwargs):
    responses = old_getaddrinfo(*args, **kwargs)
    return [response
            for response in responses
            if response[0] == socket.AF_INET]
socket.getaddrinfo = new_getaddrinfo
```

Isso força o request com ipv4